# Can't upload .osc to local Rails Port instance

Tags: openstreetmap, mapserver, merge, josm

I have been experimenting with a local instance of Rails Port. I used `osmosis` to load a small `pbf` of my neighborhood. Using JOSM I edited some data on the local instance. Then a few weeks later I downloaded the latest `osm` of my neighborhood. Using `osmosis` I generated a `.osc` file, a diff between my postgres database and the new `osm` file. I opened the `.osc` file with `JOSM` where I could see the changes, but I couldn't upload the changes to local postgres database. It shows a conflict and upon giving sync, both entire data set and specific node it wouldn't upload ans keep showing the same conflict message.

Error message from JOSM: 'Conflicts detected Uploading failed because the server has a newer version of one of your nodes, ways, or relations. The conflict is caused by the node with id 1,472,108,803, the server has version 1, your version is 2. Click to Synchronize node 1,472,108,803 only to synchronize the conflicting primitive only. Click to Synchronize entire dataset to synchronize the entire local dataset with the server.Click Cancel to abort and continue editing.' If I click on any of them it syncs with the database and gives me the same conflict error.

I have a user account on local Rails Port instance with what I can upload data manually and I changed the OSM Server URL to point my local instance which is http://localhost:3000/api

Comment: Showing the exact error message is always helpful.

Comment: edited the question and added the exact error message from JOSM.

Comment: Please see https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/60724/cant-upload-osc-to-local-rails-port-instance for a discussion of the same problem. It looks like your client has a newer version of the object than the server, consequently the server rejects it.

Comment: actually that was asked by one of my friend and we are working on the same project. unfortunately it did not help much.

Comment: First you should try to determine why the client has newer data than the server. The client didn't download its data from this server but from another server, which is likely the cause of the problem.